# Blender is not using multiple CPU cores on Linux

Tags: rendering

I just started learning Blender today from YouTube. I am on Arch Linux x86_64. But  stuffs like Subdivision Surface, Skin are taking long time. So I opened up gnome-system-monitor and saw that Blender is using only 25% of the CPU.

How can I improve the performance by making it use all the available 4 cores?

Comment: I doubt that Blender has a lot of multithreaded processes apart from rendering. If your PC utilizes all cores during render, then it is working as expected

Comment: Actually sometimes it doesn't use multicores. For example, stuffs like subdivision surface and skin doesn't use all the cores. After choosing subdivision surface view to 6 and dragging the object around takes very long time and uses only one core! And I got it, sometimes I see all the cores are being used!

Comment: In general some processes are easy to make parallel and some aren't. Either way, to support multi-core evaluation, the code has to be explicitly written that way. There is plenty of old code in Blender that has not yet been updated to take advantage of this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have also read that there's some stuff that doesn't utilize the concept of multithreading. This could make them slow, but reliable in some way.